# Retrofit Beginner About POJO's

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

Today, I have tried to use retrofit library instead of volley.
My Problem is I'm getting this result in my response.

```
Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
```

I'am trying to parse the Google response and it returns me that error.

My Pojo is this.

```
public static class googleMap{
    String icon;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }

    public void setIcon(String icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    String id;
}
```

for my interface is this.

```
 public interface GoogleCLient {

    @GET("json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&type=restaurant&name=cruise&key=AIzaSyBe7DiT-2GeoUiFEUJkP-TL4JBR2yFoLu4")
    Call<List<googleMap>> loadMaps();
}
```

And for my code for setting and getting the response is this.

```
  String URL2 = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch";
    GitHubClient client = ServiceGenerator.createService(GitHubClient.class, URL2);
    Call<List<googleMap>> call2 = client.loadMaps();
    call2.enqueue(new Callback<List<googleMap>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<googleMap>> call, retrofit2.Response<List<googleMap>> response) {
            Log.e("Res:", response.body().size());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<googleMap>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("Err:", t.toString());
        }
    });
```

I have made the Servicegenerator in my other class so i can just call it anytime and just put the URL as a parameter.
My first try is working(Different URL tho).
But when it comes to Google Places search,
My code is not working.
Where I made a mistake and how can I make it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you're using [this](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchResponses) API, you're getting back an object with your results array in it:

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [
       ...
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

So define a POJO for it:

```
public class SearchResult {
    List<googleMap> results;

    public void setResults(List<googleMap> results) {
        this.results = results;
    }

    public List<googleMap> getResults() {
        return results;
    }
}
```

and return this instead with your call

```
public interface GoogleCLient {
    @GET("json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&type=restaurant&name=cruise&key=AIzaSyBe7DiT-2GeoUiFEUJkP-TL4JBR2yFoLu4")
    Call<SearchResult> loadMaps();
}
```

Comment: so this SearchResult() is another Pojo?

Comment: @CharlesGalvez yes it is. Yours is incomplete. You need to have an object for the root, not an array.

Comment: I am still receiving this error after i added the pojo. 
Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Comment: Sorry. its now working. I didn't change my interface now its okay. thanks

Comment: So the logic is, another pojo if theres one more json array or json object.?

Comment: @CharlesGalvez that's how I'm doing it. But I'm not perfectly sure if it's the right or perfect way to do it.

Comment: Sorry i already checked the answer but i do still have a question. 
I can't get the value for this..

Comment: results: [
{
geometry: {
location: {
lat: -33.86755700000001,
lng: 151.201527
}
},

Comment: Are U getting result?

Comment: @CharlesGalvez your `googleMap` only stores `icon` and `id`. You have to extend your whole model to match the result. Maybe try to generate it automatically with http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ or similar pages.

Answer (score 0):

What's the JSON response the Google API is providing you?  My guess is that your POJO is wrong and that you should expect an object containing a list of objects rather than a list of objects

Update:
You have indeed a complex object containing more objects.  Using a Json to Java POJO online tool such as http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/, you'd get an object like this:

```
public class GoogleMapsResponse {
private Results[] results;

private String[] html_attributions;

private String status;

public Results[] getResults ()
{
    return results;
}

public void setResults (Results[] results)
{
    this.results = results;
}

public String[] getHtml_attributions ()
{
    return html_attributions;
}

public void setHtml_attributions (String[] html_attributions)
{
    this.html_attributions = html_attributions;
}

public String getStatus ()
{
    return status;
}

public void setStatus (String status)
{
    this.status = status;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "ClassPojo [results = "+results+", html_attributions = "+html_attributions+", status = "+status+"]";
}
}
```

Note that you'd have a few more objects that you'd need to define.  See the link above for a full list

Comment: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&type=restaurant&name=cruise&key=AIzaSyBe7DiT-2GeoUiFEUJkP-TL4JBR2yFoLu4

this link. provided with my key.